# PostMessage — how to send int array?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, postmessage

How to send int array:

```
int *pars = new int[4];
pars[0] = 87675;
//...
pars[3] = 1024;
PostMessage(?);
```

And then properly receive it and clear memory:

```
LONG OnMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
//?
}
```

Everything in one process.

Comment: A way would be to `new` on posting and `delete` on revieving. It's not a good way, but this is win32. Or, if you can, make a global/singleton to store the data

Comment: `WM_COPYDATA` might be one way to do it if it is across processes. Otherwise I sometimes just use the appclass as a go between - depending on the context and needs of the app.

Comment: Within one process (I updated the post).

Comment: I'd say maybe you want to consider on whether you want to use PostMessage or SendMessage? If you use SendMessage, you can manage the memory clean up in the sending routine and the receiver does not have to clean up. Also, SendMessage() sends it "now" whereas PostMessage puts it in the queue and deals with it when your pump your message loop and it gets to that message. But, only you know for sure on your situation whether it'd be better to use Send instead of Post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within a single process you can just pass addresses via `LPARAM`.

```
    int *pars = new int[4];
    pars[0] = 87675;
    //...
    pars[3] = 1024;
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_MY_CUSTOM_MSG, 0, (LPARAM)pars);
```

Then take it from `lParam`, use and then free:

```
LONG OnMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    int *pars = (int*)lParam;

    // use it ...

    delete[] pars;
}
```

Not ideal, but this is WinAPI ...

For a more RAII-like approach, wrap the pointer in `unique_ptr`:

```
LONG OnMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> pars((int*)lParam);

    // use it normally ...

    // it's freed automatically
}
```